# Bootstrap or media queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a question pondering since some time.
Given a requirement to build an application, say a website or anything, to make it responsive would you opt for bootstrap or media queries? why would you choose one over the other?

Any other way to make it responsive? do let us know.

Comment: bootstrap uses media queries.

Comment: That is correct, but my question is still unanswered

Comment: You are asking if you should use bootstrap or media queries. You can't use bootstrap without them. If you don't want to use media queries then you will need to use javascript to detect screen size, feature detection etc. and add classes accordingly so that you can use descendant selectors to control the layout.  Choosing boostrap is taking care of all the initial setup for you, if you want to use media queries from scratch then its going to take you a lot longer to get setup.

Comment: You can learn fluid design and judicious use of max-width and keep media queries to a min.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more appropriate question would be "should I use Bootstrap with EVERYTHING it comes with (including media queries), or just write my own media queries?"

Bootstrap is a responsive framework, which means it comes with media queries just as if you were to write your own (like `@media (min-width: 50em){...}`). If you are wanting more control over your site and don't want to mess with all the styles and components that Bootstrap ships with, then do it yourself from scratch. Otherwise, using Bootstrap is not a matter of "using media queries or not". It's a matter of "using a framework or going it alone".

Probably a shameless plug, but you could checkout the [BareKit](http://a2labs.github.io/barekit/) framework I authored. It's like Bootstrap in that it comes with a responsive grid, media queries and some JavaScript components, but has no "visual" styling, so you can customize and build your site to your own taste.